# Why doesn't my Angular.js fiddle work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, jsfiddle

I'm just trying to copy tho example here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/320_complex_grouping

My fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/92u8jtkd/9/

The HTML code is very simple:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p ng-show="lastChange">Last grouping change: {{ lastChange }}</p>
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-edit ui-grid-selection class="grid" style="width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add code here, do not give external references for code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle and now it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/92u8jtkd/26/

You missed two dependencies:

```
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css">
```

And the `$http.get` at the correct path:

```
$http.get('http://ui-grid.info/data/500_complex.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed following dependencies,

```
<script src="/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
 <script src="/release/ui-grid.css"></script>
and third point is $http.get('/data/500_complex.json')
the url should be  http://ui-grid.info/data/500_complex.json
```

Hope this will help you, Good luck.

Comment: ui-grid.css is a stylesheet not a script